# Remove object from an array on selection of dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular8

Working with Angular 8 , I have problem in my logic.

**There are two drop downs:**

**First Drop down**

- The options in the first drop down is shown from an array of objects

  **Example Code, ts:**

```
       {rs_id: "a5f100d5-bc88-4456-b507-1161575f8819",
        rs_code: "100006",
        rs_name: "Leanbox Logistics Solutions Pvt Ltd"} ,
```

```
     {rs_id: "a5f100d5-bc88-4456-b507-116157523345",
     rs_code: "123406",
     rs_name: "xysa Solutions Pvt Ltd"} , 

     {rs_id: "a5f100456-b507-116157523345",
     rs_code: "123406223",
     rs_name: "Solutions Pvt Ltd"} , 
  ]
```

html

```
<option>
    <select  (change)="getRsId($event)"  > 
    <option [value]='data.rs_id' *ngFor='let data of s_rsList  ; let i = index'> {{data.rs_name}} </option>



</select>
```

> - **options in second drop down is shown from same array of objects , but object selected in the first dropdown should be removed from Array
>     .**

Full code example:

***slackbliz link ->***

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7lgyfe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

html

```
<div> 

<p> First DropDown </p>

<select  (change)="getRsId($event)"  > 
<option [value]='data.rs_id' *ngFor='let data of s_rsList  ; let i = index'> {{data.rs_name}} </option>
</select>


<p> Second DropDown </p>

<select  (change)="getRsId($event)" > 
<option [value]='data.rs_id' *ngFor='let data of r_rsList  ; let i = index'> {{data.rs_name}} </option>
</select>



</div>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  s_rsList  :any = [
    {rs_id: "a5f100d5-bc88-4456-b507-1161575f8819",
     rs_code: "100006",
     rs_name: "Leanbox Logistics Solutions Pvt Ltd"} , 


     {rs_id: "a5f100d5-bc88-4456-b507-116157523345",
     rs_code: "123406",
     rs_name: "xysa Solutions Pvt Ltd"} , 

     {rs_id: "a5f100456-b507-116157523345",
     rs_code: "123406223",
     rs_name: "Solutions Pvt Ltd"} , 
  ]

  r_rsList : any = [] 


  constructor(){}


  getRsId(value){



    console.log(value);


    let Rsindex =   value.target['selectedIndex'];
    console.log(Rsindex);
    this.r_rsList.splice(Rsindex, 1);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a ngModel values on the select elements and use a `get` property to filter the 2nd array

```
  selected_R_Item;
  selected_S_Item;

  get r_rsList() {
    return this.s_rsList.filter(item => item.rs_id !== this.selected_S_Item )
  }
```

Htm;

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected_S_Item"     > 
<option [value]='data.rs_id' *ngFor='let data of s_rsList  ; let i = index'> {{data.rs_name}} </option>
</select> 

<select  [(ngModel)]="selected_R_Item"   > 
<option [value]='data.rs_id' *ngFor='let data of r_rsList  ; let i = index'> {{data.rs_name}} </option>
</select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khsv4r?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways how to achieve expected behavior, one of them is:

We can set getter for `r_rsList` that will clone `s_rsList` except selected item.

working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjttxn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Just use 2 different array:

In your TS:

```
s_rsList = [.....] //your principal array
s_rsList_2;

constructor() {
  this.s_rsList_2 = this.s_rsList;
}

 getRsId(value){
    let Rsindex =   value.target['selectedIndex'];
    console.log(Rsindex);
    this.s_rsList_2 = this.s_rsList.filter((value, index) => index != Rsindex  )
  }
```

In your HTML

```
<select  (change)="getRsId($event)"  > 
  <option [value]='data.rs_id' *ngFor='let data of s_rsList  ; let i = index'> 
  {{data.rs_name}} </option>
</select>




<select  (change)="getRsId($event)" > 
  <option [value]='data.rs_id' *ngFor='let data of s_rsList_2; let i = index'> 
  {{data.rs_name}} </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your ts file. This is working as per my understanding of your requirement.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  s_rsList  :any = [
    {rs_id: "a5f100d5-bc88-4456-b507-1161575f8819",
     rs_code: "100006",
     rs_name: "Leanbox Logistics Solutions Pvt Ltd"} , 


     {rs_id: "a5f100d5-bc88-4456-b507-116157523345",
     rs_code: "123406",
     rs_name: "xysa Solutions Pvt Ltd"} , 
  ]

  r_rsList : any = [] 


  constructor(){}


  getRsId(value){



    console.log(value);
    let Rsindex =   value.target['selectedIndex'];
    console.log(Rsindex);
    this.r_rsList=this.s_rsList.slice();
    this.r_rsList.splice(Rsindex,1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `(change)="getRsId($event)"` from 2nd select dropdown, change `getRsId` to:

```
 getRsId(value) {
   this.r_rsList = this.s_rsList.slice();
   this.r_rsList.splice(value.target["selectedIndex"], 1);
 }
```